# Using R to retrieve the column in data.frame with column name in the sequence

Tags: r, csv

I want to just run a small data let say `data<-read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE)` with column name `100, 102, ..., 300` (Note: in data.frame, R would add `X` in front of the column name since it is a number. How I can choose the data frame from spesific column name with sequence 4? Which is

```
X100   X104   X108  X112  ...
 1.2    1.3    1.1   1.5   
 1.2    1.3    1.1   1.5
```

I tried here but not working

```
new<-data[,c(paste0("'X",seq(100,300,4),"'",collapse=",")))
```

Comment: Reproducible example please. Maybe use `dput` or construct a toy dataset that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Use this: `paste0("X", seq(100,300,4))`

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus its works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a little too much in your `paste` function.  Try this instead:

```
new <- data[, paste0("X", seq(100,300,4))]
```

That should work based on the info you provided